# How to change the font size of elsearticle latex class?

Tags: pdftex

I have written my draft in elsevier latex template and my supervisor has vision problem and asking me to increase the size of the font. I tried to edit elsearticle.cls file but nothing changed. How can I increase the font size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried placing `\fontsize{13}{16}\selectfont` below your `\begin{document}`? That should work.

The first number is the desired font size, the second number is the baselineskip, so generally the second number should be 1.2 times larger than the first (as a starting point, do whatever is most legible and looks best).

However, you'll usually get better answers to LaTeX questions on https://tex.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thank you very much this worked, what about the tables? I want the tables to remain as 10p size

Comment: maybe just `\fontsize{10}{15}\selectfont` before each table? I'm not sure how to automate it unfortunately.

Comment: Though you'll probably have to set `\fontsize{13}{16}\selectfont` again after the table